Use GraphQL Documents on Apollo Client queries
I have created a Rest API application in Typescript, using NestJS and querying a GraphQL server using Apollo Client.
I currently have my queries hard-coded like this:
const query = "query { example }";

this.apolloClient.query({
  query: gql`
    ${query}
  `,
});

But I would like to move those queries to .grapql files and use them in the queries as DocumentNode.
example.graphql
query {
  example
}

import example from "example.graphql";

this.apolloClient.query({
  query: example,
});

Can I have some help on what I need to do to get that?
I tried creating a graphql.d.ts file with some code like this:
declare module "*.graphql" {
  import { DocumentNode } from "graphql";
  const value: DocumentNode;
  export default value;
}

But I keep getting Cannot find module "example.graphql" or its corresponding type declarations error.
import example from "example.graphql";
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


You shouldn't import .grapql files, instead you should import the auto generated hooks that rely on those .grapql files. 

I'm going to give you some guidance, but you have to apply it to your on case. 
1)  Install GraphQL and Required Packages 
npm install @nestjs/graphql graphql-tools graphql apollo-server-express @graphql-codegen/cli @graphql-codegen/typescript @graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers  
2) Configure GraphQL Module in NestJS 
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { join } from 'path';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'), // auto-generate schema file
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

3) Define GraphQL Schemas (SDL) 
Example src/schema.graphql <-- !Here¡ 
type Query {
  hello: String!
}

4) Set Up Codegen Configuration 
codegen.yml 
overwrite: true
schema: "src/schema.graphql"
generates:
  src/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-resolvers"


5) Run Codegen to Generate Types 
package.json 
{
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "graphql-codegen"
  }
}


npm run generate

In the codegen.yml you define the output, in this case is src/graphql.ts 
Then after generate finish, you can import the generated hooks, when you do some modifications to your .graphl files you need to run: npm run generate again 
Hope this can give you some guidance (https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/getting-started).
